# Does pressure exist at the center of a solid Sphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, solid-mechanics

If it does , can heating an object cause change in it? How can the relation between change in temp and internal pressure be derived?

Comment: I've deleted a comment that was attempting to answer the question. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements to the question and requesting clarifications, not for answering.

Comment: "Pressure" is more commonly used to describe fluids. The aggregate effect of forces between the molecules or atoms of a solid substance usually is called _[stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics))_.

Answer (score 1):

A solid, such as a sphere, is a statically indeterminate structure; it can
(often does) contain internal stresses, and those can be pressure in
the interior (or a variety of other conditions).

It is possible to make a structure that has negative pressure in the center,
holding (in tension) to all the surface of that item.   Prince Rupert drops
are such a structure (easily made by cooling liquid glass) [see a demonstration here](https://youtu.be/OCJwHrvutGk)  that
exhibit remarkable resistance to surface cracks such as are the starting
point for normal fractures.

Tempered glass is a (slightly less spectacular) example of internal stresses
created for a useful purpose.

In terms of creating high pressure inside a solid, an inclusion inside a diamond
crystal can be laser-heated to create truly high pressures, but there are few
practical applications for such stressed items (unless superballs' high bounce
properties are 'practical').

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. The only pressure source in the center of solid sphere would be due to gravity force of a sphere.
Using hydrostatic equilibrium equation for fluids :
$$ {\frac {dP}{dr}}=-{\frac {GM(r)\rho (r)}{r^{2}}} $$
and integrating it, one can arrive at central pressure **upper limit** formula which is the same for calculating central pressure in stars:
$$ P_{central} = \frac{5\,G \, m^2}{4 \, \pi \, R^4} $$

For Earth center this estimate gives pressure about $\approx 575~ \text{GPa}$ ($5.75 \times 10^{11} \text{Pa}$).

Btw, it's worth to note that for usual everyday objects this inner center pressure would be very small. For example if we take a $1 \text{kg}$ sphere with $1 \text{m}$ radius, it will have $ 10^{-11} \text{Pa}$ central pressure. So for all practical reasons this central pressure can be neglected for small objects with a mass $m \ll m_{_\text{Earth}}$. However for celestial objects this pressure becomes very important.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula for $P_{central}$ have a factor of "3/8" instead of "5/4", and inserting Earth values of $m=5.97\times 10^{24}$ kg and $R=6371$ km in the formula her gives $6\times 10^{11}$ Pa,  not $10^{17}$ Pa. See the answer to "[What is the pressure at the center of the Earth? (Or a neutron star)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/639121/145491)".

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've made an error in Earth core pressure estimate,- it's really about $575~ \text{GPa}$, post fixed. But, I'm not sure about exact factor, these calculations were made 3 years ago, so details are lost, I would need to re-check that from a new, maybe you are right, I don't know.